# wp_enqueue_script with dependencies doesn't work

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts, wp-register-script, bug

I'm having this code:

```
wp_register_script('parent','parent.js', array('child'), '1', true);
wp_register_script('child', 'child.js', array('grandchild'), '1', true);
wp_register_script('grandchild', 'grandchild.js', array(), '1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('parent');
```

and it works fine, rendering `grandchild.js`, then `child.js`, then `parent.js` in footer.

Every combination of just parent and child works fine, regardless of TRUE or FALSE 'render in footer'. But when I register 'child' to be rendered in head instead:

```
wp_register_script('parent','parent.js', array('child'), '1', true);
wp_register_script('child', 'child.js', array('grandchild'), '1', FALSE);
wp_register_script('grandchild', 'grandchild.js', array(), '1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('parent');
```

Then `child.js` gets rendered in head, `parent.js` gets rendered in footer, **and `grandchild.js` is not rendered at all !** Even though there is obviously a dependency for it.

Looks like a bug to me. **Am I missing something? Shouldn't it work?**

Thanks!

Comment: How can you fool WordPress rendering grandchild in footer and depended JS (child) in header ?

Comment: Could actually be this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35643 , that one will be fixed in 4.5

Comment: Sumit, I'm not sure I understood you. Try enqueueing just two items: parent and child, play with it's "head" and "footer" settings, it's pretty good and logical.

I expect multi level dependencies to be as good as 2 level dependencies. Under no circumstance I expect one of scripts I depend on to just silently never render. This is wrong.

Comment: Tried nightly build, still getting this weird behaviour. Bug I mentioned in comment above have been fixed, it's not it. Filed a new one https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35873

Comment: This is related to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168688/loading-a-script-with-a-dependency-is-unloading-another-scripts-dependency and https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25247 - I'll comment on your ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **bug** in Wordpress.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35873

As far as I can see, it can currently be fixed with https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/35873/35873.3.patch, if you are reading this some time later, it has probably already been fixed for your Wordpress version.

As a temporary workaround, set parent dependencies to both child and grandchild. This way `grandchild.js` will not get lost:

```
wp_register_script('parent','parent.js', array('grandchild', 'child'), '1', true);
wp_register_script('child', 'child.js', array('grandchild'), '1', FALSE);
wp_register_script('grandchild', 'grandchild.js', array(), '1', true);
```

Comment: Nice one Dima Stefantsov, thanks to you it looks like this will finally get into core.